# Is it possible to crate a e4 men in E3 view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a Viewpart (Eclipse 3), Is it possible to use e4 toolbar or e4 menu in a Viewpart,?. If possible how to do it.

Comment: This is far too vague, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Hello @greg-449, I have an RCP Product developed in e3. I want to create a e4 toolbar in one of my view of my product. But I am not sure whether  it is possible to have e4 toolbar in e3 view.

Comment: If you mean something defined in the Application.e4xmi then no, toolbars in the e4xmi belong to a specific MPart so you can't connect it to an e3 view.